# Dataframe greater than zero and less than zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a big dataframe like this with millions rows. I want to do something to apply to this dataframe quickly.

```
df value
   10
   -1
   20
   ...
   -3
   -4
   -50
   12
```

I want to know the **most efficient** way to determine if the value is greater than 0, the value will * 2. If the value is less than 0, the value will *3. The output will be the dataframe like this

```
df value
   20
   -3
   40
   ...
   -9
   -12
   -150
   24
```

my script is

```
dff = df.value
for i in range(len(dff)):
   if dff[i] > 0:
         dff[i] = dff[i] * 2
   elif dff[i] < 0:
         dff[i] = dff[i] * 3
```

Comment: This is conditional creation of a Series. Lots of options here: [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19913659/15497888)

Answer (score 1):

Let `s` be:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(-10,11,10**6))
```

Best solution among the alternatives:

```
y = np.where(s > 0, s * 2, s * 3)
```

Timed:

```
CPU times: user 11.3 ms, sys: 2.21 ms, total: 13.5 ms
Wall time: 11.8 ms
```

Your solution:

```
%%time
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] > 0:
        s[i] = s[i] * 2
    elif s[i] < 0:
        s[i] = s[i] * 3
```

Timed:

```
CPU times: user 17.7 s, sys: 51.3 ms, total: 17.8 s
Wall time: 17.9 s
```

An alternative:

```
%%time
y = s.map(lambda x: x*2 if x>0 else x*3)
```

Timed:

```
CPU times: user 308 ms, sys: 37.5 ms, total: 345 ms
Wall time: 371 ms
```

Another alternative:

```
%%time
mask = s>0
y = s.where(mask, s * 2).where(~mask, s * 3)
```

Timed:

```
CPU times: user 31 ms, sys: 7.43 ms, total: 38.4 ms
Wall time: 37.2 ms
```

Comment: `y = np.where(s > 0, s * 2, s * 3)`  is likely significantly faster than map. Would you consider running the timing?

Comment: You're right, @Henry. Updated the answer.